# Changing Laravel password reset mail to queued

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-mail

I'm struggling with queues in Laravel as I never used them before. I'm overriding the default reset password email with help of the `toMailUsing` method and a dedicated service provider:

```php
class MailServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
            $url = url(route('password.reset', ['token' => $token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()]));
            dispatch(new SendEmail($url, $notifiable));
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my `SendEmail` job class:

```php
class SendEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct($url, $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new ResetPassword($this->url, $this->user);
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send($email);
    }
}
```

And the mailable itself:

```php
class ResetPassword extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $url;
    protected $user;


    public function __construct($url, $user)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.password_reset', ['url' => $this->url, 'user' => $this->user]);
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? I successfully queue the job and receive email, but get an error:

```
Trying to get property 'view' of non-object
```

**Stack trace: https://flareapp.io/share/87nOGYM5#F59**

Here is my previous, working code:

```php
//Provider
ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $token) {
    $url = url(route('password.reset', ['token' => $token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()]));
    return new ResetPasswordMail($url, $notifiable);
});

//Mailable
class ResetPassword extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $url;
    protected $user;


    public function __construct($url, $user)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        $address = 'noreply@' . config('app.domain');
        $name = 'Lorem ipsum';
        $subject = config('app.name') . ' - Próba zresetowania hasła';

        $this->to($this->user)->subject($subject)->from($address, $name)->markdown('emails.password_reset', ['url' => $this->url, 'user' => $this->user]);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly where the problem is. You should include it in your question.

Comment: Doesn't `toMailUsing` need to return an instance of the `MailMessage` notification? You wouldn't dispatch the job from within the closure, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very complicated, so I'm not sure where your problem is. But if it helps, here's what I do to send a queued custom password reset email.

1. `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword::sendPasswordResetNotification()` is inherited by the `User` model; override it to use your custom notification.

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace App;

   use App\Notifications\UserPasswordReset;

   class User extends Authenticatable
   {
       public function sendPasswordResetNotification(string $token): void
       {
           $url = route('password.reset', [
               'token' => $token,
               'email' => $this->getEmailForPasswordReset()
           ]);
           $this->notify(new UserPasswordReset($url));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build a custom notification and make sure it is queuable

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace App\Notifications;

   use App\Mail\UserPasswordReset as UserPasswordResetMailable;
   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

   class UserPasswordReset extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
   {
       use Queueable;

       protected $url;

       public function __construct(string $url)
       {
           $this->url = $url;
       }

       public function via(User $notifiable)
       {
           return ["mail"];
       }

       public function toMail(User $notifiable)
       {
           return new UserPasswordResetMailable($this->url, $notifiable);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Your existing mailable should work fine, though here's what mine looks like:

   ```php
   <?php

   namespace App\Mail;

   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
   use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
   use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

   class UserPasswordReset extends Mailable
   {
       use Queueable;
       use SerializesModels;

       public $user;
       public $url;

       public function __construct(string $url, User $user)
       {
           $this->user = $user;
           $this->url = $url;
       }

       public function build()
       {
           return $this->
               ->with(["message" => $this])
               ->to($this->user->email)
               ->from(config("mail.from.address"))
               ->subject(__("Password Reset"))
               ->text("email.reset_plaintext")
               ->view("email.reset_html");
       }
   }
   ```

No service provider needed, no job class needed.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work, but not sure if it's queueing properly - php artisan queue:listen doesn't show anything.

@Edit
Really need it to be mailable with markup

Comment: To be honest I've never looked too much into it. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#queueing-notifications) says "Once the `ShouldQueue` interface has been added to your notification, you may send the notification like normal. Laravel will detect the `ShouldQueue` interface on the class and automatically queue the delivery of the notification." So I take them at their word!

Comment: And if you want Markdown, replace `text()` and `view()` methods with `markdown()`, or use your existing `Mailable` instance. Should work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

**I used below code for sending ResetPassword mail with queue in Laravel 8.x**

create new ResetPasswordNotification class via `php artisan make:notification ResetPasswordNotification` and replace it's code with this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
}
```

And add method `sendPasswordResetNotification` method in your App\Models\User class:

```
<?php

...
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
...    

/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

then run `php artisan queue:work` and test